# cellForRowAtIndexPath issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My app currently has a tableview that has 3 different cells, each with its own separate custom cell. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` stub method, I have the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let directionsCell = YelpInfoTableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YelpInfoDirectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YelpInfoDirectionCell
        directionsCell.business = currentBusiness
        return directionsCell

    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let contactCell = YelpInfoTableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YelpInfoContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YelpInfoContactCell
        contactCell.business = currentBusiness
        return contactCell

    } else {
        let infoCell = YelpInfoTableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YelpInfoInfoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YelpInfoInfoCell
        infoCell.business = currentBusiness
        return infoCell
    }
}
```

And I set the `dataSource` and `delegate` in the `viewDidLoad` method, all of which is located in my Detail VC. I set a breakpoint at the stubbed method and the problem is that it hits that breakpoint as soon as the VC that triggers the Detail VC, therefore going into my `else` statement for the `indexPath`.

How do I get it to be that if the user presses the 1st cell, it loads cell A, 2nd cell, Cell B, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean "load" the cell.

Comment: I mean return the cell

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you want the cell to do when you tap on it. Load more data? Change the data in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var businessMock: Business = Business(dictionary: currentBusiness)

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let directionsCell = YelpInfoTableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YelpInfoDirectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YelpInfoDirectionCell
//            directionsCell.business = currentBusiness
            directionsCell.business = businessMock

            return directionsCell

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let contactCell = YelpInfoTableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YelpInfoContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YelpInfoContactCell
            contactCell.business = businessMock
            return contactCell

        } else {
            let infoCell = YelpInfoTableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YelpInfoInfoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YelpInfoInfoCell
            infoCell.business = businessMock
            return infoCell
        }
    }
```

You must create the Business Object first. Also, the indexPath starts at 0, so start at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are 0-based in Swift. The first cell is index 0, second has index 1, third has index 2, etc. If you're expecting the first row to qualify for the first `if` clause, you should look for `indexPath.row == 0` instead of `indexPath.row == 1`.